# HDMI audio output problems with Radeon card

Tags: 12.04, sound, hdmi

No matter how much advice I follow, I still cannot get any audio to come out through my HDMI connection. I've tried downloading the latest proprietary FGLRX graphics drivers, and I've also gone into `/etc/default/grub` and altered

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

into this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"
```

But still I cannot get any sound nor can I get HDMI sound output to show up in Sound Settings or Pulse Audio Volume Control.  I can get video to show up just fine on my monitor through HDMI so I'm sure this problem is fixable! I know this is an old problem with Ubuntu, but any new strategies into the problem would be much appreciated.

With that being said, here are some of my specs:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- AMD Radeon HD 7520G

Comment: Never mind people. The upgrade to 12.10 fixed it (as long as I use the proprietary fglrx drivers instead of the open source one).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I read this and did the trick, I hope it works for you too:
Open the terminal and:

`sudo apt-get install fglrx`

After a reboot and selecting the correct output in "System Settings > Sound > Output" everything worked like a charm. Let's see whether it stays that way...

Answer (score 0):

Adding radeon.audio=1 to the splash in ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 do not seem to work although 13.04 it works and audio plays well, this may be due to the new 3.8 kernel and if so you can install it by going here:

http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/03/install-linux-kernel-384-in-ubuntulinux.html